# Unable to install Bazel using Bazelisk

Tags: software-installation, golang

I want to install Bazel on linux 20.04 version. I have already installed go.
I am trying to use the command `go install github.com/bazelbuild/bazelisk@latest` mentioned in [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source).
Somehow I am unable to locate where the bazel file is installed.
After running the command `sudo go install github.com/bazelbuild/bazelisk@latest`, terminal printed the following:

```
go: downloading github.com/bazelbuild/bazelisk v1.11.0
go: downloading github.com/mitchellh/go-homedir v1.1.0
go: downloading github.com/hashicorp/go-version v1.3.0
```

My go env variables are as follows:

```
GOBIN="/home/somepc/Desktop/TryBasel"
GOCACHE="/home/somepc/.cache/go-build"
GOENV="/home/somepc/.config/go/env"
GOMODCACHE="/usr/local/go/bin/pkg/mod"
GOTOOLDIR="/usr/local/go/pkg/tool/linux_amd64"
```

I have only included the env variables, which I felt were important to solve this issue. Kindly let me know in the comments if more information is needed!

Comment: I also used to fail with bazelisk, so the easy way was used for e.g. all Ubuntu and Debian OS: 4.2.2 https://sourceforge.net/projects/bazel.mirror/files/4.2.2/bazel_4.2.2-linux-x86_64.deb/download , i.e. `bazel_4.2.2-linux-x86_64.deb` .... Ref. https://sourceforge.net/mirror/bazel/activity/?page=0&limit=100#623ca17a14b4036ce0752aa3

Comment: If you managed to fix this, let us know!

Comment: @M.K I did not manage to fix it yet. I wanted to install Bazel for using Tensorflow, now I use Google Collab for that purpose.

Comment: I managed to fix it but I don't exactly remember what I did, as I had to research quite some time and I was trying different solutions. If I remember anything I will let you know! Collab sounds like a good option! @AJ

Comment: it's in `~/go/bin/bazelisk`